# NoSuchFrameException(frame_reference) in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is the exception that I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/navendu/lead-generator/python_scripts/tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 12, in <module>
    driver.switch_to_frame("http://103.251.43.139/~ksebuser/orumabills/upload/billview/")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 789, in switch_to_frame
    self._switch_to.frame(frame_reference)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/switch_to.py", line 87, in frame
    raise NoSuchFrameException(frame_reference)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException: Message: http://103.251.43.139/~ksebuser/orumabills/upload/billview/
```

Here is the python code that I am running:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.kseb.in/index.php?option=com_wrapper&view=wrapper&Itemid=813&lang=en")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(7)
driver.switch_to_frame("http://103.251.43.139/~ksebuser/orumabills/upload/billview/")

ele = driver.find_element_by_id('t_consumer-no_5')
ele.send_keys("some text")
```

Here is the link to the web page. I am trying to automate form filling in that website
http://www.kseb.in/index.php?option=com_wrapper&view=wrapper&Itemid=813&lang=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException: Message: http://103.251.43.139/~ksebuser/orumabills/upload/billview/
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to locate the desired `<iframe>` element.

---

Seems you were pretty close. The `<iframe>` have the *src* attribute set as `http://103.251.43.139/~ksebuser/orumabills/upload/billview/`. So mentioning the *src* attribute would have solved your issue.

However, as the the desired element is within an `<iframe>` so to send a *character sequence* within the element you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `XPATH` with *src* attribute:

    ```
    driver.get("http://www.kseb.in/index.php?option=com_wrapper&view=wrapper&Itemid=813&lang=en")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@src, 'ksebuser/orumabills/upload/billview/')]")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='userInputText']"))).send_keys("Navendu_Pottekkat")
    ```
  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR` with *src* attribute:

    ```
    driver.get("http://www.kseb.in/index.php?option=com_wrapper&view=wrapper&Itemid=813&lang=en")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src$='ksebuser/orumabills/upload/billview/']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.userInputText"))).send_keys("Navendu_Pottekkat")
    ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Consumer]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the name or id attribute to switch. May be try `driver.switch_to_frame("iframe")` or `driver.switch_to_frame("blockrandom")`

Answer (score 0):

The frame is not URL.

You can right click on the page to check if there has frame.
It will show "View Frame Source".
[image]

And find the id/name/index of frame.

[image]

```
driver.switch_to_frame("blockrandom") # frame id
```

Reference: https://www.techbeamers.com/switch-between-iframes-selenium-python/

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to switch by the `src` attribute, however `switch_to_frame` receive `id`or `name` attributes or `WebElement` as parameter. You should also replace the `sleep()` with `WebDriverWait`

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(ec.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it('blockrandom'))
```